# convert the given array to an array of Boolean where Each element is true if the number is a prime number, and false otherwise

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, boolean, primes

I need to find out either a number is Prime or not in an array. in the beginning I thought it's easy, but .. :)

First I tried this version :

```js
function primeValues(arr) {
  let newArr = []
  for( let el of arr) {
    if (el <= 2 ) {
      newArr.push(true)
    }
    for (let j=2; j<el; j++) {
      if (el%j === 0) {
        newArr.push(false)
      } 
      if (el%j !==0 ) {
        newArr.push(true)
      } 
    }    
  }
  return newArr;
}  

console.log(primeValues([17, 3, 21]));
```

But every time it goes through `for loop`, It pushes `True` or `False` in my new array  :/`

```
(35) [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

what should I do? :/

Comment: What outcome are you expecting? You're pushing `true` or `false` into the array.

Comment: on reflection, I find this question to be a very good and educational starting point to explain how creating algorithms has become an art (++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way...

```js
console.log( JSON.stringify( primeValues( [17, 3, 21 ] )))

function primeValues(arr)
  {
  let result = [], modulo;
  for( let el of arr) 
    {
    if (el <= 2 ) 
      result.push(true)
    else                  // this one is missing in your code
      {
      modulo = 1          // modulo initial assignement must be there
      for (let j = 2; j < el; j++) // or (let j=3; j<el; j +=2)
        {                        // see Alexey Zelenin explanations 
        modulo = el % j
        if (modulo === 0) 
          {
          result.push(false)
          break          // this other one is missing in your code
          } 
        } 
      if (modulo !== 0)  result.push(true) // test last modulo value
      }                                  // outside the loop (and it's scope)
    }
  return result;
  }
```

But you might prefer to code it like this:

```js
console.log( JSON.stringify( primeValues([ 17, 3, 21 ] )))

function primeValues(arr)
  {
  let result = []
    , isNotPrim
    ;
  for (let el of arr) 
    {
    isNotPrim = false    
    if (el > 2)
    for (let j = 2; j < el; j++) 
    if (isNotPrim = !(el %j))   
      break
      ;
    result.push( !isNotPrim )
    }
  return result;
  }
```

Comment: First version is more understable for me . I did not really understand why Modulo Assignment changed result so much.. but that I will try to figure out myself :) Thank you!

Comment: @MariamJikia at the **end of** `for (let j=2; j < el; j++)`, `j` value is equal to `el` value and the following test will look like `if (el % el !== 0)`. except that this `j` no longer exists and this test will throw an error--> `j` it is out of the `for(let j ...)` scope.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function primeValues(arr) {
  return arr.map(element => {
    const x = Math.abs(element);
    if(x <= 2) return true;
    if(x % 2 === 0) return false;
    for(let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i+=2) {
      if(x % i === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(primeValues([7,9,11,13,-21,2,54]));
```

I added some optimizations to the code

1. We check only odd numbers because an element can't be divisible by an even number if it's not already divisible by 2.
2. We don't need to check ALL the numbers less than "element" - we need to check only numbers from 3 to square root of the element. If you need any additional explanation why - I can give it.
3. I suggest using "map" instead of creating an array and pushing there - it's more efficient. Also, it protects you from missing "else" and "break" statements - every check immediately finishes when `true` or `false` is added to the answers list.

UPD: Added `Math.abs` function call, so negative numbers will be processed correctly.

Comment: I  started learning JS not long ago. did not know about MAP yet :) Thank you!